# How to use task$select to select features to be removed instead of to be kept

Tags: mlr3

I have a dataset with many features and I am trying to remove unwanted features at the task step using task$select(c("A"...)

Instead of listing the features I want to keep (a lot), I want to list the features I want to remove (a few) using Selector_invert. how do I that? I also wonder if I can do removeconstants and collapseFactors at the task steps.

I was able to do using pipelines in the learner step using the following code

```
preproc = po("select",selector = 
         selector_invert(selector_name(feature_list))) %>>%
po("removeconstants", ratio =  0.05) %>>% 
po("collapsefactors")
```

Answer (score 4):

> I am trying to remove unwanted features at the task step

Just use `setdiff`:

```r
library(mlr3)
task = tsk("pima")

# remove feature `age`
task$select(setdiff(task$feature_names, "age"))
```

> I also wonder if I can do removeconstants and collapseFactors at the task steps.

You can apply the pipeline to the task:

```r
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3pipelines)

preproc = po("removeconstants", ratio =  0.05) %>>%
  po("collapsefactors")

preproc_task = preproc$train(task)[[1]]
```

If you do resampling, it is recommended to include these preprocessing steps in the learner.